# Mockito- testing a statment with multi setParameter in createdNamedQuery gives null

Tags: jpa, mockito

```
em.createNamedQuery(ProductHistory.SEARCH, ProductHistory.class).setParameter("productId", 
productId).setParameter("zId",zId)
```

.executeUpdate();
return a null pointer but the folowing work

```
  em.createNamedQuery(ProductHistory.SEARCH, ProductHistory.class).setParameter("productId", 
productId).executeUpdate();
```

when i i have multi setParameter on the CreateNamedQuery it throw a null pointer

Comment: None of the code you posted shows how you're using Mockito. Can you paste the relevant portions of your test?

Answer (score 0):

Why would even want to unit test that code? Mocking the entity manager? Put that into some meaningful abstraction and then you will have no problems with unit testing your class.

THe class containing the entity manager would be tested by your integration tests when accessing for instance an in memory DB or sth like that.